# C Language - Windows has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, heap-corruption

I am coding C language in Visual Studio C++.

In the first calling of this function there is no problem. It makes all of process but in the second calling VS give "Windows has triggered a breakpoint" error.
However, I compile and run the code in Linux, there is no problem.

```
void printDataPagePersons(int pageNumber)
{   
    Person* pageofCity = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person)* RECORD_COUNT);
    printf("page of city : %d\n",sizeof(*pageofCity));

    FILE* fp;
    fp=fopen("x.dat", "rb");
    fseek(fp, PAGE_SIZE*pageNumber,SEEK_SET);
    fread(pageofCity, PAGE_SIZE,1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    //OTHER PRINTING PROCESSES...
}
```

Comment: You probably have a buffer overflow. You don't provide sufficient detail to diagnose the error. There are several definitions and values missing.

Comment: 1) Check the result of `fopen` 2) Use `%zu` to print `size_t` 3) Last, but not least, Post a [mcve]

Comment: why are you using `PAGE_SIZE` there instead of `sizeof(Person) * RECORD_COUNT` (or more so, reading `RECORD_COUNT` records of `sizeof (Person)`

Comment: @ Antti Haapala :
I must read 1 disk page in this assignment. For example my record size is 200, and my disk page size is 1024. I know, Ican fit 5 record into this disk page and 24 bytes are NULL. But I must read exact 1 disk page(1024 byte).

Comment: Then you must allocate 1 disk page.

Comment: Wow !. It works @ Martin James. Thank you !.
But what is the main problem ?.

Comment: You were reading more memory than you had allocated, so UB:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you allocate a buffer:

```
Person* pageofCity = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person)* RECORD_COUNT);
```

This is the size of that buffer:

```
sizeof(Person)* RECORD_COUNT
```

You then read data from a file into that buffer at this line of code:

```
fread(pageofCity, PAGE_SIZE,1, fp);
```

There you are telling the *fread* function to read a *PAGE_SIZE* of bytes into that buffer.

I'm guessing the cause of your problems is this condition is also true:

```
PAGE_SIZE > sizeof(Person)* RECORD_COUNT
```